# Last Div Flickering During jQuery Hover Animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Here's my code: http://jsfiddle.net/ZspZT/

As you can see from the example, the fourth div block is flickering pretty badly, particularly on the hover-over effect, but also occasionally with the other divs as well.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post the relevant code here as well.

Comment: Can you post some of your code here too? Out network blocks URLs containing "ZspZT"

Comment: @musefan Oddly specific.

Comment: stop() is crucial when multiple events are using animation.

Comment: Simple fix would be to add `background-color: #999999;` to `#four-ways-slider`. The effects are still bugged, but there's no flickering.

Comment: @OptimusCrime That alone wouldn't fix his problem. If you try mousing over the fourth sub-div, you'll find that the flicker is caused by it actually disappearing from under the mouse. When that happens, the mouseover is cancelled and the expected behavior fails.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that the easing function built into .animate is causing your percentage widths to add up to greater than 100%, causing the last sub-DIV to disappear. There are a few ways to solve this.

When I replace your percentage widths with fixed numerical widths, the problem vanishes. I used this in the code below (and your code had a LOT of redundancy to reduce):

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    var speed = 450;
    $('.four-ways-slide').hover(function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            width: 425
        }, speed).siblings().stop().animate({
            width: 25
        }, speed);
    }, function() {
        $(this).siblings().andSelf().stop().animate({
            width: 125
        }, speed);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/ZspZT/10/

Another possibility is to use percent widths that add up to 99% instead of 100%, and set a background color on the container DIV to hide the gap. Adding linear easing to the .animate method helps keep the total width from exceeding 100%:

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    var speed = 450;
    $('.four-ways-slide').hover(function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            width: '75%'
        }, speed, 'linear').siblings().stop().animate({
            width: '8%'
        }, speed, 'linear');
    }, function() {
        $(this).siblings().andSelf().stop().animate({
            width: '24.5%'
        }, speed, 'linear');
    });
});

#four-ways-slide-4,#four-ways-slider{background:#999999;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/ZspZT/9/

Answer (score 1):

try using 'mouseenter' and 'mouseleave' rather than 'hover'.  also you should assign variables rather than repeating divs

```
    var one = $('#four-ways-slide-1');
var two = $('#four-ways-slide-2');
var three = $('#four-ways-slide-3');
var four = $('#four-ways-slide-4');
var all = $('.four-ways-slide');

thisIn = function(){
    all.animate({width:'8%'},{duration: 450,queue:false});
};

thisOut = function(){
    all.animate({width:'25%'},{duration: 450,queue:false});       
};

one.mouseenter(function(){
    thisIn();
    $(this).animate({width:'76%'},{duration: 450,queue:false});

        one.mouseleave(function(){
            thisOut();
            $(this).animate({width:'25%'},{duration: 450,queue:false});
        });

});
```